# AJAX Post to AWS API Gateway not working (405 Method not allowed), but its working with Postman

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, post, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-405

I built a small HTML form with bootstrap and I'm hosting it as a static Website in an AWS S3 Bucket. Then I added an AWS API Gateway and Lamda function so that the data from this form is stored into an AWS DynamoDB.

At this point, I can "Post" raw JSON Data via Postman to the API Gateway and the Lambda function is storing the data in the DynamoDB table. I created a .ajax in my Website to gather the data and send it as JSON. But I always get this error:

[image]

My AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form>button[type=submit]").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let apiGatewayInvokeURL = 'https://gxt8igxck7.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/test';
    
    var body = {
    KundenID : $("#KundenID").val(), 
    Vorname : $("#Vorname").val(), 
    Nachname : $("#Nachname").val(),
    Telefonnummer : $("#Telefonnummer").val(),
    Email : $("#Email").val(),
    Strasse : $("#Strasse").val(),
    Hausnummer : $("#Hausnummer").val(),
    PLZ : $("#PLZ").val(),
    Ort : $("#Ort").val(),
    Ankunftszeit : $("#Ankunftszeit").val(),
    Abreisezeit : $("#Abreisezeit").val(),
    datencheck : $("#datencheck").val() 
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : apiGatewayInvokeURL,
        crossDomain: 'true',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(body),

        success: function () {
            $("#form").trigger('reset');
            alert('Successfull');
           },
        error: function (response) {
              alert('Failed: HTTP ' + response.status);
          }
          });  
       });
 });
```

I just can't seem to find the reason for this error. The API Gateway can clearly handle POST requests, but maybe I got the wrong idea about what I'm doing. If you need any further data just let me know.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is the Network Tab of Chrome while submitting:

[image]

It seems the Post request is going to the S3 Bucket Server instead of the API Gateway?
And Content-Type of my Request Header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, shouldn't it be application/json?

**EDIT LAST**

Found the Error.. apparently

```
$("#form>button[type=submit]").click(function(event)
```

was not working as intended. Because of this

```
event.preventDefault();
```

was not called correctly and the form natively POSTED to the Website HOST which is S3 Bucket and is not allowing POST Requests. I changed the Code to

```
    $("#btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Now it's working like a charm after fixing some minor CORS errors.
Maybe this helps someone